# checking if else statement and looping for the file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

**I want to loop through files and check whether each file contains any spelling errors**.

```
 If yes then return 1 else -1.
```

Now, I can check whether there is a spelling error for 1 file. But it can't loop for more than 1 and return 1 if get error else -1.

checkSpelling.m file

```
function suggestion = checkSpelling(word)

h = actxserver('word.application');
h.Document.Add;
correct = h.CheckSpelling(word);
if correct
  suggestion = []; %return empty if spelled correctly
else
  %If incorrect and there are suggestions, return them in a cell array
  if h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).count > 0
      count = h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).count;
      for i = 1:count
          suggestion{i} = h.GetSpellingSuggestions(word).Item(i).get('name');
      end
  else
      %If incorrect but there are no suggestions, return this:
      suggestion = 'no suggestions';
  end

end
%Quit Word to release the server
h.Quit
```

f20.m file

```
for i = 1:10

data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\',int2str(i),''),'r')
CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData
fclose(data2);

 word = regexp(CharData, ' ', 'split')

[sizeData b] = size(word)

suggestion = cellfun(@checkSpelling, word, 'UniformOutput', 0)
if sum(cellfun(@isempty,suggestion))==0
feature20(i)=-1;
else
feature20(i)=1;
end
end
```

I get to loop for the file, and also checking, but it return me the wrong results when suggestion is empty (1)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not clear. Do you want a collection of all the errors in the file, or the first one it runs into?

Comment: `but it cnt loop for more than 1` - what problem are you seeing exactly? Does it just stop after one? Does it give you an error?

Comment: do not need to collect all the error. the suggestion will return me whether the article gt error or not, if suggestion is empty that means no error, if suggestion got return me the suggested word that means got error. So, I have to check whether the suggestion is empty or not, if is empty that return -1, else 1. That is for 1 file or 1 article. There have 10 have and 10 article to loop. At the end the output will be feature20=[1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1]<---got error and no error in those specific article.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why `suggestion==0` would work, because it should be a cell array coming out of `cellfun`

Comment: yes, "??? Undefined function or method 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> f20 at 12
    if suggestion==0" how to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want the output to be a vector of values, one for each file. The values would be 1 if suggestion contains errors and -1 if it is empty.

The problem is that since `suggestion` is a cell array, you cannot compare it using the boolean operator `==' . If you want a vector of outputs, you will also need to index`feature20` each iteration. Here's a potential fix.

**It sounds like `isempty(suggestion)` gives the wrong answer, so try this one:**

```
if sum(~cellfun(@isempty,suggestion))==0
    feature20(i)=-1;
else
    feature20(i)=1;
end
```

Comment: yes, but it return me the wrong results when my suggestion is empty, suggestion  empty return 1~

Comment: i know there is correct in your checking. But it return me the wrong results when my suggestion is empty. any ideas?

Comment: still return me the same results as just now~

Comment: @user3340270 I would make sure that the individual elements of `suggestion` are in fact empty. I can't do any actual debugging without your data.

Comment: i just write some correct sentences with no spelling error in file 2 and got spelling error in file 1. I have printscreen my suggestion results as above. suggestion 1: got error, suggestion 2: no error

Comment: @user3340270 I see what the problem is - I left off a `~` (boolean NOT). Should be good now